# How do i get a direct download link for my file on Linux VPS

Tags: linux, hyperlink, download, hosting, vps

I have recently just got a subscription to a Linux VPS (Ubuntu)

I have logged into the VPS using FileZilla and uploaded my .png file to the VPS. But when i travel to the ip address in my web browser then i am unable to navigate to the directory for the file. I have apache2 running on the web server so when i navigate to the VPS using my browser it says this

It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Can someone please teach me on how to upload my .png file correctly so i can have a download link something similar to

http://myipaddress.com/home/files/mypicture.png

Would highly appreciate any knowledge applicable to my problem. If someone helps me solve the problem then i will happily tip them some cryptocurrency :)

Answer (score 0):

You must put your public files in the directory published by the web server: the "DocumentRoot".

By example, it may be:

```
/var/www
```

The published files must also be readable by the Web Server process.
The Apache server on Debian runs with the "www-data" user/group, by default.